# Can ServiceStack operation naming convention be overriden?

Tags: naming-conventions, servicestack, dto

I need to define a DTO class for a ServiceStack service. Service stack uses convention based on class names, so if my class is called Transmission, the corresponding service will use expose metadata with  a type "Transmission" used in HTTP operations.

But I already have Transmission class - the one my DTO object will be mapped to. To avoid confusion I want to define TransmissionRequest DTO (probably something better than just "Request" suffix) but keep "Transmission" in exposed service metadata. I don't find a way to override the ServiceStack convention, so it calls types exposed in service operations after their respective C# classes.

Is there a way to override exposed types (e.g. using attributes) or this is hard wired convention that can't be customized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Auto-Route Generation Strategies](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#auto-route-generation-strategies) in the [Routing wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing) for different ways of customizing, removing or injecting different auto-route generated strategies.