# Override ServiceStack operation name

Tags: servicestack, metadata, naming-conventions

I have some ServiceStack services with DTOs with a suffix of Query and the response a suffix of Result. Everything works well however this generates operation names with the full Query suffix name,

I would like to remove that and I don't see a way. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071180/can-servicestack-operation-naming-convention-be-overriden) sounds like you can customize it through the route naming conventions, but the route is easily specified already. I just want to change the operation name. Thus I am confused.

For instance in the [metadata page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Metadata-page) how would I change the operation "AssignRoles" to something else like "Assign_XYZ_Roles"?

Comment: Have you tried inheritance; you could add another Request DTO "Assign_XYZ_Roles" that inherits from "AssignRoles".

Answer (score 1):

Just create another requestDTO that inherits from your suffixed DTO and then update the service to use the child DTO

```
public class HelloQuery : IReturn<HelloResponse>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Route("/hello/{Name}")]
public class Hello : HelloQuery
{
}

[DefaultRequest(typeof(HelloQuery))]
public class MyServices : Service
{
   public object Any(Hello request)
   {
     // you could cast the Hello DTO back to HelloQuery here
   }
}
```

Comment: I have thought about this, but then I might as well name the original how I want.

Comment: I've assumed you might have a good reason for not wanting to rename the DTO. As If you were trying to override one of servicestack's build-in DTOs. But renaming the DTO and following servicestack's naming convention (Request/Response) is the right way to go.